# rand() produces numbers above set range in recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, random, function-call

My understanding is that this produces a random number between 10 and offset:

```
random = (rand() % 10) + offset;
```

offset gets incremented by 1 but never goes above 10, yet when I run this code the variable random gets set to numbers > 10.

code in question:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void gen(int offset)
{
    int random;

    if (offset != 10)
    {
        random = (rand() % 10) + offset;
        cout << "random should be between: " << 10 << " and " << offset << endl;
        cout << "random: " << random << endl << endl;
        Sleep(500);
        gen(++offset);
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(373);

    gen(1);
    cin.get();
}
```

and the output:

random should be between: 10 and 1

random: 7

random should be between: 10 and 2

**random: 11**

random should be between: 10 and 3

random: 3

random should be between: 10 and 4

**random: 13**

random should be between: 10 and 5

random: 10

random should be between: 10 and 6

**random: 13**

random should be between: 10 and 7

**random: 16**

random should be between: 10 and 8

**random: 14**

random should be between: 10 and 9

**random: 18**

Comment: You code produces numbers between offset and offset+9. You need something like 10 + rand()%(offset - 11). It will give you what you want. Anyway it is shitty code. Just use C++11 random generators.

Comment: `(rand() % 10)` produces a number from 0 to 9.  so `(rand() % 10) + offset` returns a number from offset to offset+9

Answer (score 1):

`(rand() % 10)` returns value in range [0, 9], so `(rand() % 10) + offset` will return value in range [offset, offset + 9].

If you want to return value in range [offset, 10] you'd need `(rand() % (11 - offset)) + offset` for offsets less then 11.

Also you should probably use [std::uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) to get random integer in range.

Answer (score 0):

`(rand() % 10)` results in a number between 0 and 9, to which you then add `offset` The first time `rand() % 10)` resulted in 6, to which you added 1. thus `7`. The second time, `rand() % 10)` resulted in 9, to which you added 2, thus `11`.